# emailing content of a text file on unix platform

Tags: python

I am using the following piece of code to email the content of gerrit.txt which is HTML code but its not working?it doesnt show any errors but doesnt work the way its supposed to.any inputs on how to fix this?

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from subprocess import check_call,Popen,PIPE

def email (body,subject,to=None):
      msg = MIMEText("%s" % body)
      msg['Content-Type'] = "text/html;"
      msg["From"] = "userid@company.com"
      if to!=None:
          to=to.strip()
          msg["To"] = "userid@company.com"
      else:
          msg["To"] = "userid@company.com"
      msg["Subject"] = '%s' % subject
      p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t"], stdin=PIPE)

def main ():
    Subject ="test email"
    email('gerrit.txt',Subject,'userid')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're writing to the PIPE.

Answer (score 1):

The reason nothing is being sent is because once you open the sendmail process, the message is never written to it.  Also, you need to read the contents of the text file into a variable to include in the message.

Here is a simple example that builds off your code.  I didn't use the MIMEText object for everything so modify it to suit your needs.

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from subprocess import check_call,Popen,PIPE

def email (body,subject,to=None):
      msg = MIMEText("%s" % body)
      msg['Content-Type'] = "text/html;"
      msg["From"] = "you@yoursite.com"
      if to!=None:
          to=to.strip()
          msg["To"] = to
      else:
          msg["To"] = "user@domain.com"
      msg["Subject"] = '%s' % subject
      p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t", "-f" + msg["From"]], stdin=PIPE)
      (stddata, errdata) = p.communicate(input="To: " + msg["To"] + "\r\nFrom: " + msg["From"] + "\r\nSubject: " + subject + "\r\nImportance: Normal\r\n\r\n" + body)
      print stddata, errdata
      print "Done"


def main ():
    # open gerrit.txt and read the content into body
    with open('gerrit.txt', 'r') as f:
        body = f.read()

    Subject ="test email"
    email(body, Subject, "from@domain.com")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Actually ..gerrit.txt contains HTML code..I want the output to be emailed in HTML format,not the same exact content...Eg: contents of gerrit.txt http://pastie.org/8264638

Comment: Just add a `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF8` header to the message and it will be in HTML format.

Comment: Can you tell which part in the code this should be added?isnt it already there in the code?

Comment: `(stddata, errdata) = p.communicate(input="To: " + msg["To"] + "\r\nFrom: " + msg["From"] + "\r\nSubject: " + subject + "\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF8\r\nImportance: Normal\r\n\r\n" + body)`